# EWS Concurrent stream subscription

Tags: exchangewebservices

When I try to open stream subscription to Exchange 2013 via EWS I get the following:
"Unable to open Exchange connection: You have exceeded the available subscriptions for your account.  Remove unnecessary subscriptions and try your request again."
It's obvious that there is a limit of MaxConcurrentConnection which I believe is 20.
But the question is how to get number of active subscriptions or force unsubscribe some of users.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is not related to the "MaxConcurrentConnection" but due to exceeding the value for "EWSMaxSubscriptions".

> EWSMaxSubscriptions – Defines the maximum number of active push, pull,
>   and streaming notification subscriptions that a user can have on a
>   specific Client Access server at one time. This is budgeted
>   differently for different Exchange versions.

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945066(v=exchg.150).aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2011/06/23/exchange-online-throttling-and-limits-faq.aspx

Increase the value of EWSMaxSubscriptions on your exchange server and try.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I went through this link. And there is some light "The server starts to return errors when the number of open connections reaches approximately 20 for a use". But no concrete documented value.
And since we faced this problem for approx. 12 users I assumed that CONCURRENT access caused this issue. Maybe we didn't close connection properly and our application tried to open 21 st connection... something like that. 
So opening and disposing of EWS connections is a dark area

Comment: 2nd link is dead just fyi :)